# write result as matrix form

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape, svd

let us consider following matrix

```
a=[1 2 3;2 3 4;3 4 5;4 5 7]

a =

     1     2     3
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     4     5     7

let us consider it's svd

[U E V]=svd(a)

U =

   -0.2738   -0.8708   -0.0062   -0.4082
   -0.3984   -0.2552   -0.3309    0.8165
   -0.5230    0.3605   -0.6557   -0.4082
   -0.7020    0.2159    0.6786    0.0000


E =

   13.5093         0         0
         0    0.6482         0
         0         0    0.2797
         0         0         0


V =

   -0.4032    0.8699    0.2841
   -0.5437    0.0220   -0.8390
   -0.7361   -0.4928    0.4641
```

if consider  kronecker product of columns of U and V matrix

```
kron(U(:,1),V(:,1))

ans =

    0.1104
    0.1489
    0.2015
    0.1606
    0.2166
    0.2932
    0.2109
    0.2843
    0.3849
    0.2831
    0.3817
    0.5167
```

but it is  returning as vector form,but i need  matrix form,so how can i transform it to matrix insider kron product?maybe i should you reshape command,but could you help me to  do it?thanks in advance

Comment: See if this result makes sense to you - `kron(U(:,1),V(:,1)')`

Comment: it makes sense and please  post it as an answer with result to accept it

Comment: Oh I don't know if that talks about "good research effort". I would not mind at all if you take the honor and post it as your answer.

Comment: i have posted it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have  consider following  change as Divakar adviced and it works fine

```
X=kron(U(:,1),V(:,1)')

X =

    0.1104    0.1489    0.2015
    0.1606    0.2166    0.2932
    0.2109    0.2843    0.3849
    0.2831    0.3817    0.5167
```

thanks my friend for your help

Comment: +1 for this answer (and for @Divakar's comment), but my usual warning: be careful that `'` includes a complex conjugate. To just transpose use `.'`

Comment: in this case we have only real variables,but thanks for your advice